# Progressive loop calculations

Tags: c#, .net

Ok. So I'm trying to have a program.. where the user enters his salary and then the program will calculate his salary for the next four years with a raise of 2.5% each year.

I feel like I have done this completely wrong, because my loop is only calculating one time.. its not even showing four salary's.. not to mention having them each raised 2.5% each time.

```
private void btnDisplay_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{     
    int count;
    for (count = 1; count <= 4; count++)
    {
        decimal Raise;
        decimal Salary;
        decimal Sum;
        decimal Total;

        Raise = Convert.ToDecimal(0.025);
        Salary = Convert.ToDecimal(txtSalary.Text);
        Sum = Salary * Raise;
        Total = Salary + Sum;
        label2.Text = Total.ToString("c");       
 }
```

`txtSalary` is whatever the user entered salary is. 
`label2` is the display of the calculation.

---------------- UPDATE: I have updated the code with the final product. Thanks to everyone for helping out especially Patrick Hofman! You are the best.. I couldn't have done it without you. ------------------------

```
        private void btnDisplay_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        decimal salary = Convert.ToDecimal(txtSalary.Text);
        decimal raise = 0.025m;

        decimal previous = salary;

        for (decimal year = 1; year <= 4; year++)
        {
            decimal sum = previous * (1 + raise);
            previous = sum;

            listBox1.Items.Add(sum.ToString("c"));
        }
```

Comment: Did you use the debugger?
Hint: COmputers are fast.... why on earth should your pc show something other than the last step?

Comment: You destroy all the calculated values in your loop. move the declarations out of loop

Comment: what have you entered in textbox `txtSalary`?

Comment: I moved "  decimal Raise
            decimal Salary;
            decimal Sum;
            decimal Total;" But the calculations are the same still.

Comment: @user3601679 now you override the labels2' value. It will only display the last one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should have something like this:

```
private void btnDisplay_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    decimal salary = Convert.ToDecimal(txtSalary.Text);
    decimal raise = 0.025m;
    decimal total = 0;
    decimal previous = salary;

    listBox1.Items.Add("Start: {0:N2}", salary);

    for (int year = 1; year <= 4; year++)
    {
        decimal sum = previous * (1 + raise);
        previous = sum;

        total += sum;

        listBox1.Items.Add("Year {0}: {1:N2}", year, sum);
    }

    listBox1.Items.Add("Total: {0:N2}", total);
}
```

Note I made some changes to the variables. Some were moved to keep them over the for loop.

The steps:

1. Start with setting the start point (`previous`) to the salary.
2. For each year, multiply the previous year's salary with the raise percentage +1.
3. Set the previous and add that year's salary to the `total`.
4. Show the total in the label.

Comment: Can it be used without the String Builder?

Comment: That is only for the MessageBox. The number is shown on the label. You can remove all references to StringBuilder.

Comment: OK. I have changed the label to a listbox. but when the total is added to the list box is is only displaying one calculation and it is incorrect. :(  

Also can you explain why yours works so well and mine did not?

Comment: -1 Homework questions need help not the whole code. SO is not "write my homework" kind of site

Comment: @user3601679: of course. Updated the answer to include the steps.

Comment: :/ it still only works with the messagebox. When I use a label or listbox it only gives me one calculation and it is waay off.

Comment: I will take a look for you.

Comment: Its off because for some reason its adding them all together instead of displaying 4 different numbers.

Comment: Were you able to figure it out why its only displaying one calculation Patrick? I really appreciate it..

Comment: @user3601679: I updated the code. It is okay now? You need to show the intermediate value every time in the loop.

Comment: Thank you Patrick you're the best. I got it working with a few edits to your code. thank you, thank you!

Answer (score -1):

```
int count;
Salary = Convert.ToDecimal(txtSalary.Text);

for (count = 1; count <= 4; count++)
{
    Salary *= 1.025m;
}

label2.Text = Salary.ToString("c");
```

You need to make sure you're retrieve the salary once at teh beginning and don't overwrite it till the end.

Comment: This will not satisfy the OP's requirement for "each year" even though it appears syntactically correct.

Comment: @jeffdot `syntactically correct`?  `Salary * 0.025m;`

Comment: @L.B I'd have sworn to all the gods that it used to say `Salary *= 1.025` there but I see there's no edits made.  Thanks for the alert.

Comment: I updated your code a little to make it compile, and hopefully work as you intended.

Answer (score -2):

**Problem 1:** You are declaring the variables inside the forloop.so each time they are initialised with their default values.

**Solution 1:** inorder to retain their last assigned values you need to move the declaration of the variables outside the loop.

**Problem 2:** you are not able to see the results/changes as you are updating the label inside the for loop without any delay.so evatually you can only see the last calculated result.

**Solution2:** You need to either create 4 different labels to show the 4 different results or you need to wait for some time for updating the label results in each iteration by using timer functionality.

Try This: using `LabelArray`

```
Label[] lblSalaries = new Label[4];
private void CreateControls()
{

        int x = 0, y = 10;

        for (int i = 0; i < lblSalaries.Length;i++ )
        {
            lblSalaries[i] = new Label();
            x += 60;
            lblSalaries[i].Size = new System.Drawing.Size(50, 30);
            lblSalaries[i].Location = new System.Drawing.Point(x,y);
            Controls.Add(lblSalaries[i]);
        }
}
private void btnDisplay_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        int count;
        decimal Raise;
        decimal Salary;
        decimal Sum;
        decimal Total;
    CreateControls();
    for (count = 1; count <= 4; count++)
    {
        Raise = Convert.ToDecimal(0.025);
        Salary = Convert.ToDecimal(txtSalary.Text);
        Sum = Salary * Raise;
        Total = Salary + Sum;
        lblSalaries[count-1].Text = Total.ToString("c");
    }
}
```

Comment: -1 since the problem has nothing to do with the number of text labels.

Comment: Its showing an error for lblSalaries[count-1].Text = Total.ToString("c"); It says you cant apply indexing with [] to an expression

Comment: @user3601679: you need to create 4 different labels , check my edited answer,